# Laravel, display data where all Ids are matched

Tags: php, laravel

In `controller index function`
I'm picking up which news ids are matching with a pack id:

```
$content_pack_news_array = DB::table('content_pack_news')->where('content_pack_id' , $content_pack_id)->get();
```

Using `dd` I get this result which I need to access `news_id` of all elements in it

```
  Illuminate\Support\Collection {#3017 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => {#2376 ▼
      +"news_id": 2
      +"content_pack_id": 2
    }
    1 => {#3010 ▼
      +"news_id": 4
      +"content_pack_id": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

How to return data that matched with ids:

```
"news_id": 2
"news_id": 4
```

Inside:

```
$news = News::with(['media', 'assigned_content_packs'])->where('id' , $news_id)->get();
```

If I use

```
$content_pack_news = DB::table('content_pack_news')->where('content_pack_id' , $content_pack_id)->first();
```

It works but it gets only first matching item to display.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to join the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it in single query using sub query as:

```
$news = News::with(['media', 'assigned_content_packs'])
                ->whereIn('id', function($query) use($content_pack_id){
                    $query->select('news_id')
                    ->from('content_pack_news')
                    ->where('content_pack_id', $content_pack_id);
                })
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pluck, to get the ids out.

```
$newsIds = DB::table('content_pack_news')
    ->where('content_pack_id' , $content_pack_id)
    ->pluck('news_id');
```

Pluck works great in combination with `whereIn()`, that checks a column against an array.

```
$news = News::with(['media', 'assigned_content_packs'])
    ->whereIn('id' , $newsIds)
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

if i correct you only asking the first.

```
$content_pack_news = DB::table('content_pack_news')->where('content_pack_id' , $content_pack_id)->first();
```

change it to get(); then you get all records.

```
$content_pack_news = DB::table('content_pack_news')->where('content_pack_id' , $content_pack_id)->get();
```